# Problems with some keys using Apple wireless keyboard on a PC running Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, bluetooth

I am using Apple Wireless Swedish keybord connected to a Lenovo Thinkpad T550 and Windows 7
I love the keyboard but I have problems with some keys

- The "< >" key and "§" key are swapped so when I type "§" I get "<" and vice versa
- There is no delete key, so I can't delete a file or delete text to the right, there are also other programs I use that require the delete key.
- There is no home/end button so I can't move my cursor to beginning or end of a text line, I have tried all possible combinations of backspace using CTRL,ALT,FN,CMD without success. It would have been nice if i.e CMD+Left/Right Arrow acted as home/end but it seem to be mapped as a windows key as it repositions the current window

pretty much everything else is working fine

is there anything I can do to fix the problems I have with the keys?

[image]

Comment: Fn/arrow should act as page up/down/home/end. Not sure about the rest. See if this might help - http://www.howtogeek.com/115664/42-text-editing-keyboard-shortcuts-that-work-almost-everywhere/

Comment: thanks but it does not work, fn+arrow does the same as using the arrow without fn,  ctrl+arrow moves one word at a time

Comment: Then idk, sorry - works here, but I have an extended UK keyboard; might be a different response

Comment: Which keyboard layout are you using (in Region and Language settings)?

Comment: I use Swedish region